# Detect destination channel of SessionUnsubscribeEvent

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

### My Situation

I'm building a small web chat to learn about Spring and Spring WebSocket. You can create different rooms, and each room has it's own channel at `/topic/room/{id}`.

My goal is to detect when users join and leave a chat room and I thought I could use Spring WebSocket's `SessionSubscribeEvent` and `SessionUnsubscribeEvent` for this.

Getting the Destination from the `SessionSubscribeEvent` is trivial:

```
@EventListener
public void handleSubscribe(final SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
    final String destination = 
            SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage()).getDestination();

    //...
}
```

However, the `SessionUnsubscribeEvent` does not seem to carry the destination channel, `destination` is `null` in the following snippet:

```
@EventListener
public void handleUnsubscribe(final SessionUnsubscribeEvent event) {
    final String destination = 
            SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage()).getDestination();

    //...
}
```

### My Question

Is there a better way to watch for subscribe/unsubscribe events and should I even be using those as a way for a user to "log in" to a chat room, or should I rather use a separate channel to send separate "log in"/"log out" messages and work with those?

I thought using subscribe/unsubscribe would've been very convenient, but apparently Spring makes it very hard, so I feel like there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

STOMP Headers only appear in the frames relevant to your question as described here: https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#SUBSCRIBE and here: https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#UNSUBSCRIBE

Only the `SUBSCRIBE` frame has both destination and id, the `UNSUBSCRIBE` frame has only an id.
This means you have to remember the subscription id with the destination for future lookup. Care must be taken because different Websocket connections usually use/assign the same subscription ids, so to save destinations reliably, you have to include the websocket session id in your storage key.

I wrote the following method to get it:

```
protected String getWebsocketSessionId(StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor)
{
    // SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER seems to be set in StompSubProtocolHandler.java:261 ("headerAccessor.setSessionId(session.getId());")
    return headerAccessor.getHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER).toString();
}
```

`StompHeaderAccessor` is created like this:

```
StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor=StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(((SessionSubscribeEvent)event).getMessage());
StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor=StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(((SessionUnsubscribeEvent)event).getMessage());
```

This can then be used to create a unique subscription id which can be used as a key for a map to save data about the subscription, including the destination:

```
protected String getUniqueSubscriptionId(StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor)
{
    return getWebsocketSessionId(headerAccessor)+"--"+headerAccessor.getSubscriptionId();
}
```

Like this:

```
Map<String, String> destinationLookupTable=...;
// on subscribe:
destinationLookupTable.put(getUniqueSubscriptionId(headerAccessor), destination);
// on other occasions, including unsubscribe:
destination=destinationLookupTable.get(getUniqueSubscriptionId(headerAccessor));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using SessionSubscribeEvent and SessionUnsubscribeEvent is a good idea for that matter. You can get the destination if you keep track of the SessionID:

```
private Map<String, String> destinationTracker = new HashMap<>();

@EventListener
public void handleSubscribe(final SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headers = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    destinationTracker.put(headers.getSessionId(), headers.getDestination());

    //...
}

@EventListener
public void handleUnsubscribe(final SessionUnsubscribeEvent event) {
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headers = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    final String destination = destinationTracker.get(headers.getSessionId());

    //...
}
```

Comment: What happens if there are other channels a client subscribes to? I have other channels where things like available rooms are broadcast. Or, possibly, a client could subscribe to multiple rooms.

Comment: In this case you'll see the last destination in the destinationTracker. You might want to use a List instead of a String as the value type if this is important to you. Don't forget to remove the unsubscribed channels if you go that route.

Comment: But the order of the incoming subscriptions doesn't match the (reverse) order of the unsubscriptions, so unfortunately I don't see how there is mapping between channel and `SessionUnsubscribeEvent`.

Comment: I get your problem. Unfortunately, I can't test that right now, but I think your best bet would be to check the [raw message headers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/MessageHeaders.html#getRawHeaders--) - maybe the subscribtionId header is set, or something else you could use to distinguish different channels?

Comment: Alright. the headers have a key `nativeHeaders`, which leads to another map that contains the key `id`, that points to a `LinkedList` that has what seems like a per-user unique id for channels. I've tested it and it works for now, though I still feel like there has to be a better way than digging through headers...

Comment: Your point is right in general, but it seems this is not the abstraction level Spring is offering here. What you're effectively asking is that Spring offers an API to make queries into internal meta data of the STOMP broker. Given Spring offers the use of external brokers like RabbitMQ this would have some implications in my opinion. Either Spring would be tied to brokers that offer such API, or it would have to copy their functionality, hoping there is no mismatch. It's possible that they finally offer it somehow, but I currently see enough reasons to believe manual work is really needed.